# Adjust for loop to only return values based on frequency of occurence in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
index   value   value_count
0       10      1
1       50      2
2       50      2
3       20      2
4       20      2
5       30      2
6       30      2
```

I want to analyze each unique value in separate dataframes. To create separate dataframes (=`'subdf_{i}'`) I use the code:

```
results = {}

for i, j in enumerate(df.value.unique()):
    results[f'subdf_{i}'] = df[df.value.eq(j)]
```

This gives me a subdf like this for every unique value:

subdf_1

```
index   value   value_count
0       10      1
```

subdf_2

```
index   value   value_count
1       50      2
2       50      2
```

subdf_3

```
...
```

Instead of returning subdataframes for all my unique values, I'd like subdataframes to be created for only the 3 most common values (i.e. 50, 30, 20 for the example above).

How can I adjust my code above to get to this result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) on column `value` and use slicing to get top three most common column values, then use dict comprehension to store the top three `subdf` having most common values:

```
idx = df['value'].value_counts().index[:3]
results = {f'subdf_{i}': df[df['value'].eq(v)] for i, v in enumerate(idx, 1)}
```

Result:

```
print(results['subdf_1'])

   index  value  value_count
5      5     30            2
6      6     30            2
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your code to

```
df1=df[df.value_count==df.value_count.max()]

results = {}

for i, j in enumerate(df1.value.unique()):
    results[f'subdf_{i}'] = df1[df1.value.eq(j)]
```

---

By using the `groupby`

```
results = {f'subdf_{x}' : y  for x , y in df1.groupby('value')}
```